# Pandas: Check if column value is smaller than any previous column value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to check if any value of column 'c' is smaller than all previous column values.
In my current approach I am using pandas diff(), but it let's me only compare to the previous value.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'c': [1, 4, 9, 7, 8, 36]})

df['diff'] = df['c'].diff() < 0

print(df)
```

Current result:

```
    c   diff
0   1  False
1   4  False
2   9  False
3   7   True
4   8  False
5  36  False
```

Wanted result:

```
    c   diff
0   1  False
1   4  False
2   9  False
3   7   True
4   8   True
5  36  False
```

So row 4 should also result in a True, as 8 is smaller than 9.

Thanks

Comment: So, what is the expected output? It looks like the result would be False for every row. Can you please provide a more representative example?

Comment: Your question and output are not in sync.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
df['diff'] = df['c'] < df['c'].cummax()
```

Output is just as you mentioned:

```
    c   diff
0   1  False
1   4  False
2   9  False
3   7   True
4   8   True
5  36  False
```

Comment: ah I forgot about cummax, trying to figure this out for a couple hours, thanks so much!