# Pandas: How can I check multiple columns if there are any values that are smaller than previous value?

Tags: python, pandas

Solution for a single column is already provided here: [Pandas: Check if column value is smaller than any previous column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737715/pandas-check-if-column-value-is-smaller-than-any-previous-column-value).

However, my dataset consists of many columns and I don't want to brute force many codes.

Example dataset:

```
    c     d     e
0   3     5     8  
1   1     5     8  
2   5     6     8  
3   6     7     8   
4   2     1     9  
5   9     3     3
```

Desired result:

```
    c     d     e   c_diff   d_diff   e_diff
0   3     5     8    False    False    False
1   1     5     8     True    False    False
2   5     6     8    False    False    False
3   6     7     8    False    False    False
4   2     1     9     True     True    False
5   9     3     3    False    False     True
```

Is there any way to perform this task with simple lines of Python/Panda code?

Comment: _Is there any way to perform this task with simple lines of Python/Panda code?_ Most likely, yes. What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`DataFrame.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) with [`DataFrame.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html)

```
df.diff().lt(0).add_suffix('_diff')

   c_diff  d_diff  e_diff
0   False   False   False
1    True   False   False
2   False   False   False
3   False   False   False
4    True    True   False
5   False   False    True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can operate on the whole dataframe:

```
df.lt(df.shift()).add_suffix('_diff')
```

gives you

```
   c_diff  d_diff  e_diff
0   False   False   False
1    True   False   False
2   False   False   False
3   False   False   False
4    True    True   False
5   False   False    True
```

And you can join:

```
df.join(df.lt(df.shift()).add_suffix('_diff'))
```

which gives:

```
   c  d  e  c_diff  d_diff  e_diff
0  3  5  8   False   False   False
1  1  5  8    True   False   False
2  5  6  8   False   False   False
3  6  7  8   False   False   False
4  2  1  9    True    True   False
5  9  3  3   False   False    True
```