# Pandas: How can I replace all values that are smaller than the previous value in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

My question is related to another question that I have posted on stackoverflow: [Pandas: How can I check multiple columns if there are any values that are smaller than previous value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61465848/pandas-how-can-i-check-multiple-columns-if-there-are-any-values-that-are-smalle/61465950#61465950).

Now that I know that there are multiple values that are smaller than the previous values in my dataframe, I would like to replace that value with the previous value.

Example dataset:

```
    c     d     e
0   3     5     8  
1   1     5     8  
2   5     6     8  
3   6     7     8   
4   2     1     9  
5   9     3     3
```

Desired result:

```
    c     d     e
0   3     5     8
1   3     5     8
2   5     6     8
3   6     7     8
4   6     7     9
5   9     3     9
```

Is there any way to perform this task with simple lines of Python/Panda code?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. Also, can you share that sample data in a more convenient format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mask and ffill. If your dataframe data type is float, you don't need the '.astype(int)' conversion.

```
df.mask(df.diff().lt(0)).ffill().astype(int)

    c   d   e
0   3   5   8
1   3   5   8
2   5   6   8
3   6   7   8
4   6   7   9
5   9   3   9
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.cummax()` will do the trick.